# How to add a symlinked JAR to an Eclipse project?

Tags: eclipse

I am a night-shift tollbooth worker studying programming when it's too late for customers to be driving by.

I have about 20 self-learning projects in Eclipse Juno linking to `Guava`.

I initially had the `Add External JAR` of `guava-13.0.1.jar` in each project but then I learned that creating a "library project" that would export the class (`Order and Export`) is a better, faster, easier way to do this as it does not require browsing the filesystem to add the JAR via the exact full path, as long as the "library project" is added to `Java Build Path > Project > Required projects on the build path`.

Elegant, it works perfectly.

With `guava-14.0.1.jar` out I just update the *one* project reference and all projects that depend on it link to the right archive. Fantastic.

What I'd really like to do, though, is to be able to update this reference from the filesystem, via a `symlink`. A `tree` command output is worth a 1000 words:

---

```
> tree
.
├── Latest
│   └── guava.jar -> ../v14.0.1/guava-14.0.1.jar
├── v13.0.1
│   └── guava-13.0.1.jar
└── v14.0.1
    └── guava-14.0.1.jar

3 directories, 3 files
```

---

Something like that.

If I try to point to the "external JAR" from within Eclipse, though, it dereferences/resolves/readlinks the symlink, including the hard link to `guava-14.0.1.jar` rather than the symlink to `guava.jar`.

That's frustrating and counter-intuitive.

Should I be doing this via Eclipse variables? (e.g. Add Variable... Extend...)

Should I be doing this in some other, *clever* way I have not come across yet?

I must be possible to do it, right?